# How to atach to docker container with Docker.DotNet

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker.dotnet

I try to attach to docker with this code template

```
Async Function AttachToContainer(DockerHub As DockerClient, ContainerID As String, Cmd As IList(Of String), ExecCts As CancellationToken) As Task
    Dim ExecTask = Await DockerHub.Exec.ExecCreateContainerAsync(ContainerID, New ContainerExecCreateParameters With {
                     .AttachStdin = False,
                     .AttachStderr = True,
                     .AttachStdout = True,
                     .Tty = False,
                     .Cmd = Cmd
                   },
                   ExecCts)
    Try
        Dim Attach = Await DockerHub.Exec.StartAndAttachContainerExecAsync(ExecTask.ID, False)
        Await Attach.CopyOutputToAsync(
                Nothing,
                Console.OpenStandardOutput(),
                Console.OpenStandardError(),
                CancellationToken.None)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Function
```

But failed "cannot hijack chunked or content length stream" (https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockerdash/blob/master/src/Docker.DotNet/Microsoft.Net.Http.Client/HttpConnectionResponseContent.cs)

REST API working successfully, this is background of screen, console application call this code and failed. ExecTask.ID in debugger looking good  - 36f40d3f0e03b38da0f9303f2312f68b1e48a0aedf74b856f8b7a6b596da3e33

[Attach filed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX4Oh.png)

Interesting, that some other function of Docker.DotNet with the same docker working fine.

What wrong in my code?

Comment: Same problem. Found any fix for that error?

Comment: @cmart, I think Docker.DotNet is not workable program at all, therefore I use RenciSSH client to this job (SSH.NET).